# Spring Boot load beans before Validation

Tags: groovy, spring-boot-3, java-21

I am using `jakarta.validation.constraints` Validation to validate my Request body class.However, its using one of the bean properties for validation.During validation, the bean is not initialised and its causing NullPointerException.
I want to know if there is a way that this particular bean is initialised before validation.

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '3.2.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.companyname'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '21'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://artifacts.companyname.com/nexus/content/groups/master-repo-group/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
    }
}

dependencies {
    List excludeGroups  = ['log4j', 'jcl-over-slf4j', 'slf4j-api', 'slf4j-log4j12','commons-logging']
    List excludeGroovyGroups  = ['commons-logging', 'xml-apis', 'groovy', 'slf4j-log4j12', 'log4j', 'jcl-over-slf4j', 'slf4j-api']

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.18'


    implementation 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation ('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.3'){//earlier 1.1.0
        exclude(group:'org.codehaus.groovy')//--transitive
    }
    implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'

    implementation "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-groovy"
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aop'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jms:3.2.8.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-expression:6.0.10'

    implementation('org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0') {
        exclude(group:'slf4j-log4j12')
    }

    implementation('com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.3.0') {
        excludeGroups.each { exclude group : "$it" }
    }
    implementation('com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:1.14')
    implementation('com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.52') {
        excludeGroups.each { exclude group : "$it" }
    }

    implementation ('com.twilio.sdk:twilio:9.15.1')
    {
        excludeGroups.each { exclude group : "$it" }
    }

    implementation('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1') {
        excludeGroovyGroups.each { exclude group : "$it" }
    }
    implementation('net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:0.9.4') {
        excludeGroups.each { exclude group : "$it" }
    }

    implementation('org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.1.0')
    implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson')
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3')
    implementation 'com.companyname.events:event_rest_client_java:1.8-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.yammer.metrics:metrics-graphite:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api:3.4.2'

    testCompileOnly('org.objenesis:objenesis:1.3') {
    }

    implementation('org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core') {
        excludeGroups.each { exclude group : "$it" }
    }
    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'

    runtimeOnly('org.webjars:jquery:1.11.1'){
        excludeGroups.each { exclude group : "$it" }
    }

    implementation 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz'
   
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My Controller

```
package com.companyname.cts.admin.controllers

import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import jakarta.validation.Valid
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@Slf4j
class TrackingNumbersController {

    @Autowired
    ProviderGateway providerGateway

    @Autowired
    TrackingNumberService trackingNumberService

    @Autowired
    LookupService lookupService

    @Autowired
    EventService eventService

    @Autowired
    PhoneProvisionService phoneProvisionService

    @Autowired
    TrackingNumberToEventTransformer trackingNumberToEventTransformer

    @Autowired
    ConfigLoader configLoader

    static Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .enableComplexMapKeySerialization()
            .create()

    @Autowired
    HttpServletResponse response;


    @PostMapping(value = "/trackingnumbers", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    def create(@Valid @RequestBody TrackingNumberCommand trackingNumberCommand, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        log.info("creating-TrackingNumbersController. Recieved Tracking Number command for provider=${trackingNumberCommand.provider} " +
                "and trackingNumber=${trackingNumberCommand.trackingNumber}: $trackingNumberCommand")
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            //error response here
    }else{
      //success response here
  }

}
```

My Validation POJO:

```
    package com.companyname.cts.admin.controllers
    
    import com.google.gson.JsonNull
    import com.companyname.cts.admin.TargetNumberType
    import com.companyname.cts.admin.conf.ConfigLoader
    import com.companyname.cts.admin.enums.TrackingNumberSource
    import com.companyname.cts.admin.utils.PhoneNumberUtil
    import groovy.transform.ToString
    import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.AssertTrue
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull
    import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
    
    
    @Log4j
    @ToString(includeNames = true, includePackage = false)
    @Component
    class TrackingNumberCommand{
    
        @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Z]{3}_[0-9]+", message = "Global master advertiser id (GMAID) is required. Valid GMAID format is: UpCasePlatform_Id, e.g. USA_12345")
        String globalMasterAdvertiserId
    
        @NotBlank
        String targetNumber
    
        String countryCode
    
        @NotBlank
        String originalNumber
    
        String trackingNumber
    
        String provider
    
        String numberType
    
        String numberMatch
    
        @NotNull
        String country
    
        Map<String, String> options = [:]
        Map<String, String> attribution = [:]
        UUID id
        String source
    
        @Autowired
        ConfigLoader configLoader /* This is required to be initialised prior validation but its coming null*/
    
    
        @AssertTrue(message = "Country not supported")
        private boolean isValidCountry(){
            def val = country
            return this.configLoader.config.countries[val] || this.provider //NullPointerException
        }
    
    }
```

My ConfigLoader class:

```
package com.companyname.cts.admin.conf

import com.companyname.cts.admin.enums.RequestHeaders
import com.companyname.events.api.EventRestApiClient
import com.twilio.Twilio
import com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager
import org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service
import org.jets3t.service.security.AWSCredentials
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils
import wslite.http.HTTPClient
import wslite.http.auth.HTTPBasicAuthorization
import wslite.rest.RESTClient

import javax.jms.Destination


@Configuration
class ConfigLoader {

    private final String DEFAULT_ACCEPT_HEADER = RequestHeaders.DEFAULT_ACCEPT_HEADER.value
    private final String DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER = RequestHeaders.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER.value

    ConfigObject config // from groovy.util
    ConfigObject providerConfig
    ConfigObject ctsConfig

    
    //================================================INIT BLOCK====================================================//
    {
        config = new ConfigSlurper("development")// from groovy.util
                .parse(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:Config.groovy").toURI().toURL());

        providerConfig = new ConfigSlurper("development")
                .parse(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:Providers.groovy").toURI().toURL());

        ctsConfig = new ConfigSlurper("development")
                .parse(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:cts.groovy").toURI().toURL());

        config.merge(providerConfig)
        config.merge(ctsConfig)

    }

    //================================================BEAN DEFINITIONS====================================================//
    @Bean
    EventRestApiClient getEventReplyService() {
        return new EventRestApiClient(config.event.host, config.event.token)
    }

    @Bean
    RestS3Service getS3Client() {
        return new RestS3Service(new AWSCredentials(config.S3.accessKey, config.S3.secretKey))
    }

    @Bean(name = "telmetricsConnectorRestClient")
    RESTClient getTelmetricsConnectorRestClient() {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();

        map.put(DEFAULT_ACCEPT_HEADER, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        map.put(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

        return getRestClient(config.telmetricsConnector.host,new HTTPClient(), Optional.of(map))
    }

    @Bean(name = "googleAdsConnectorRestClient")
    RESTClient getGoogleAdsConnectorRestClient() {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();

        map.put(DEFAULT_ACCEPT_HEADER, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        map.put(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

        return getRestClient(config.googleAdsConnector.host,new HTTPClient(), Optional.of(map))
    }

    @Bean(name = "campaignRestClient")
    RESTClient getCampaignRestClient() {
        return getRestClient(config.campaignService.host,new HTTPClient(), Optional.empty())
    }

    @Bean(name = "campaignServiceV1RestClient")
    RESTClient getCampaignServiceV1RestClient() {
        return getRestClient(config.campaignService.v1Host,new HTTPClient(), Optional.empty())
    }

    private def getRestClient(url, HTTPClient httpClient, Optional<HashMap<String, String>> optionalHeaders) {
        httpClient.setSslTrustAllCerts(config.ssl.certs.trustall)

        RESTClient restClient = new RESTClient(url, httpClient)

        if (optionalHeaders.isPresent()) {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = optionalHeaders.get()

            if (headers.containsKey(DEFAULT_ACCEPT_HEADER)) {
                restClient.setDefaultAcceptHeader(headers.getAt(DEFAULT_ACCEPT_HEADER))
            }
            if (headers.containsKey(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER)) {
                restClient.setDefaultContentTypeHeader(headers.getAt(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER))
            }
        }
        return restClient
    }

    @Bean(name = "cachingConnectionFactory")
    def getCachingConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(new URI(config.ctsAdminAPI.brokerURL))

        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy()
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(0)
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy)

        return activeMQConnectionFactory
    }

    @Bean(name = "jmsProducerTemplate")
    JmsTemplate getJmsProducerTemplate() {
        return new JmsTemplate(getCachingConnectionFactory())
    }

    @Bean(name = "ctsReportingJobQueue")
    Destination getCtsReportingJobQueue() {
        Destination ctsReportingJobQueue = new ActiveMQQueue()
        ctsReportingJobQueue.setPhysicalName(config.ctsAdminAPI.reportingJobQueue)
        return ctsReportingJobQueue
    }

    @Bean(name = "telmetricsRestClient")
    RESTClient getTelmetricsRestClient() {
        HTTPClient httpClient = new HTTPClient()
        HTTPBasicAuthorization basicAuth = new HTTPBasicAuthorization(config.telmetrics.api.username,config.telmetrics.api.password)

        httpClient.setConnectTimeout(120000)
        httpClient.setReadTimeout(120000)
        httpClient.setUseCaches(Boolean.FALSE)
        httpClient.setFollowRedirects(Boolean.FALSE)
        httpClient.setAuthorization(basicAuth)

        return getRestClient(config.telmetrics.api.url,httpClient,Optional.empty())
    }

    @Bean(name = "twilioRestClient")
    TwilioRestClient getTwilioRestClient(){
        Twilio.init(config.twilio.accountSid as String, config.twilio.authToken as String)
        return Twilio.getRestClient()
    }

    @Bean(name = "twilioConnectorRestClient")
    RESTClient getTwilioConnectorRestClient(){
        return new RESTClient(config.twilioConnector.host)
    }

    @Bean(name = "emtexRestClient")
    RESTClient getEmtexRestClient(){
        return getRestClient(config.emtex.api.url,new HTTPClient(),Optional.empty())
    }

    private DefaultHttpClient getHttpClient(){
        PoolingClientConnectionManager poolingClientConnectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(new SchemeRegistry())
        poolingClientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(100)
        poolingClientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100)
        return new DefaultHttpClient(poolingClientConnectionManager)
    }

    @Bean(name = "advertiserRestClient")
    RESTClient getAdvertiserRestClient(){
        return getRestClient(config.advertiserService[config.platform.name],new HTTPClient(),Optional.empty())
    }

    @Bean(name = "foneDynamicsRestClient")
    RESTClient getFoneDynamicsRestClient(){

        HTTPClient httpClient = new HTTPClient()
        httpClient.setConnectTimeout(120000)
        httpClient.setReadTimeout(120000)
        httpClient.setUseCaches(Boolean.FALSE)
        httpClient.setFollowRedirects(Boolean.FALSE)
        httpClient.setAuthorization {
            new HTTPBasicAuthorization(config.foneDynamics.api.accountSid,config.foneDynamics.api.apiToken)
        }

        return getRestClient(config.foneDynamics.api.url,httpClient,Optional.empty())
    }

    @Bean(name = "softcommRestClient")
    RESTClient getSoftcommRestClient(){
        return getRestClient(config.softcomm.api.url,new HTTPClient(),Optional.empty())
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I just found that if I pass "configLoader":{} in my request body the init block re-runs and initialises ConfigLoader.However I do not want to add this extra parameter in my request body.